# Display console output on a separate window [java]

Tags: java

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game in Java and so far it's going well, but as of now, I've written my program to print to console. Is there a command to get what would currently be displayed on my console output to show up on a separate window? Something like a JOptionPane?

My console right now looks like a ticTacToe grid, and I want to maybe get a while loop to display the currentBoard to a pop-up-dialog after every set of turns. So the player can see the updated Board after every turn set.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not with the default console - it sounds like you want to create a full GUI application

Comment: Yeah, I'm mostly asking for everything with JOptionPane, and just showing the result on the console...

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect `System.out` messages to a `JTextArea` or `JTextPane`.

Check out the [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) class.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but seems a little advanced for what I need. Is there anyway to do this simply with some sort of JOptionPane command?